# Select Multiple Values in Where Time Clause Equals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, where-clause

My table looks like this:

Table 1:
Note: This table is very large in reality, with lots more columns (20ish) and rows (in the millions)

```
 |  Time      |  tmp   |  productionID  |
 |  10:00:00  |   2.2  |    5           |
 |  10:00:05  |   5.2  |    5           |
 |  10:00:11  |   7.4  |    5           |
 |  ......    |   3.2  |    5           |
 |  10:10:02  |   4.5  |    5           |
```

Note: Timeis a varchar, so I assume I need to do something like this:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(mi, 10, time), 114)
```

What I need to do is:

```
 select time, tmp 
 from mytable
 where productionid = somevalue 
 and time = first_time_stamp associated to some productionID(ie. 10:00:00 table above)
     time = 10 minutes after the first_time_stamp with some productionID
     time = 20 minutes after the first_time_stamp with some productionID
     ...25, 30, 40, 60, 120, 180 minutes
```

I hope this  makes sense.  I'm not sure what the right way to do this is.  I mean I thought of the following proccess:
-select first time stamp (with some productionID)
-add 10 minutes to that that time, 
-add 20 minutes etc.. then use a pivot table and use joins to link to table 1
There must be an easier way.

Thank you in advance for the expertise.

Sample output expected:

```
    |  Time    | tmp
    | 10:00:00 | 2.2 
    | 10:10:02 | 4.5
    | 10:20:54 | 2.3 
    | 10:30:22 | 5.3
```

Comment: Could you show some sample output?

Comment: @Aushin  See above - I've added it to my post.

Comment: So, I'm noticing the times aren't exactly spaced out by 10 minutes.  Are you looking for the first one that is at least 10 minutes later?  Also, is your specific aim getting 10, 20, 25, 30, 40, 60, 120, 180?  The pattern seems odd.

Comment: Can there be gaps in the data?  What if there were no time at the `10:20` minute... and instead say the next time was `10:23`... would that be the returned record?

Comment: Also, do you need to worry about multiple days?  And storing date/time/timestamp values as string data isn't helpful in any form - you will be better served converting it to a more correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an interval table on-the-fly and cross join it with starting time for each ProductionID, you can extract records fromMyTable falling in the same category and choose to retrieve only the first one.

```
; with timeSlots (startSlot, endSlot) as (
  select 0, 10
  union all
  select 10, 20
  union all
  select 25, 30
  union all
  select 30, 40
  union all
  select 40, 60
  union all
  select 60, 120
  union all
  select 120, 180
),
startTimes (ProductionID, minTime) as (
  select ProductionID, min([Time])
    from MyTable
   group by ProductionID
),
groupedTime (ProductionID, [Time], [Tmp], groupOrder) as (
  select myTable.ProductionID,
         myTable.Time,
         myTable.Tmp,
         row_number () over (partition by myTable.productionid, timeSlots.startSlot
                           order by mytable.Time) groupOrder
    from startTimes
   cross join timeslots
   inner join myTable
      on startTimes.ProductionID = myTable.ProductionID
     and convert(varchar(8), dateadd(minute, timeSlots.startSlot, convert(datetime, startTimes.MinTime, 114)), 114) <= mytable.Time
     and convert(varchar(8), dateadd(minute, timeSlots.endSlot, convert(datetime, startTimes.MinTime, 114)), 114) > myTable.Time
)
select ProductionID, [Time], [Tmp]
  from groupedTime
 where groupOrder = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b6de/12).

Comment: Code is very good - a couple questions (as my sql knowledge isn't as fantastic as yours)
In groupdedTime, in the convert statements why did you put: <= mytable.Time and > myTable.Time   I see what is going on, you are adding the times (in timeSlots) to the minimum times, I don't understand why we use the operators afterward.
Why does this only work giant query work on some of my productionIDs,  (I haven't looked too carefully, perhaps it because the interval times in my giant table don't match up just right)

Comment: @akwarywo Sorry for the delay. This conditions are used to eliminate `myTable.Time` which does not belong to current `timeSlot`, so that `row_number()` picks among rows in this range. Otherwise one would get `minTime` in each `timeSlot`, and there would be seven same rows. Could you please post data this query has problems with? I'd like to check it myself.

Comment: @akwarywo Oh, and there is a mistake in timeSlots - there should be one for (20, 25).

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are no missing sequence in the time. I mean if there are time values for each increment of 10minutes then this will work.

```
create table times([Time] time,tmp float,productionID int)
INSERT INTO times
VALUES('10:10:00',2.2,5),
      ('10:00:05',5.2,5),         
      ('10:00:11',7.4,5),
      ('10:00:18',3.2,5),         
      ('10:10:02',4.5,5),
      ('10:20:22',5.3,5)

select * from times

Declare @min_time time
select @min_time = MIN(time) from times

;WITH times1 as (select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as id,time, tmp from times where productionID = 5)
,times2 as(
select id,time,tmp from times1 where time=@min_time 
union all
select t1.id,t1.time,t1.tmp from times2 t2 inner join times1 t1 on cast(t1.time as varchar(5))=cast(DATEADD(mi,10,t2.Time) as varchar(5)) --where t1.id-1=t2.id
)

,result as (select MAX(time) as time from times2
group by CAST(time as varchar(5)))

select distinct t2.Time,t2.tmp from times2 t2,Result r where t2.Time =r.time order by 1
```